# Invokable.getReturnType(): cannot reproduce Guava's example from the official wiki

Tags: java, reflection, guava

In the [official Guava's `TypeToken` wiki](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ReflectionExplained#What%27s_the_return_type_of_List.get%28int%29_for_List%3CString&), there is the following example:

```
Invokable<List<String>, ?> invokable = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.method(getMethod);
invokable.getReturnType(); // String.class
```

How `getMethod` is set?

I tried the following examples:

1. First try:

   ```
   List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
   Class[] arg = { int.class };
   Method getMethod = list.getClass().getMethod("get", arg);
   Invokable<List<String>, ?> invokable = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.method(getMethod);
   System.out.println(invokable.getReturnType());
   ```

   It crashed with the following message:

   ```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: public java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int) not declared by java.util.List<java.lang.String>
       at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:145)
       at com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken.method(TypeToken.java:495)
       at tmp.LaunchClass.main(LaunchClass.java:28)
   ```
2. Second try (a little bit different though):

   ```
   List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
   Class[] arg = { int.class };
   Method getMethod = list.getClass().getMethod("get", arg);
   // changed here
   Invokable invokable = TypeToken.of(list.getClass()).method(getMethod);
   System.out.println(invokable.getReturnType());
   ```

   Doesn't crash, but doesn't return the expected result. Returned `E`. Expected result: `String.class` (as in the official wiki).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to get the method `get` from `ArrayList`. You should be getting it from `List`.

```
Class<?> clazz = List.class;
Method getMethod = clazz.getMethod("get", int.class);
```

The javadoc for [`TypeToken#method(Method)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html#method%28java.lang.reflect.Method%29) states

> Returns the `Invokable` for `method`, which must be a member of `T`.

where `T` is the type variable declared in `TypeToken`.